Windows authentication not working in IIS 10 on Windows 11 for ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I created an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. I'm hosting it on IIS on a Windows 11 machine.
I also installed the core bundle for hosting on IIS.
The issue is, when I use integrated login, I am not able to connect to the database. I get a 500.3 error. The username is not recognised.
I've tried changing the pool identity to various such as service, network etc. Also various authentication values such as anonymous enabled/disabled. All variations. I just cannot use integrated login. Works fine if I test using Visual Studio and IIS Express.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

Could you please tell me where you host the database? Inside the same server or else? Are you make sure you have used the right name for the application pool?  Besides, could you please share your current connection string?

Th edatabase is hosted locally; The connection string is fairly standard - "persist security Info=False;integrated security=True;initial catalog=devconfig;server=devw10;TrustServerCertificate=True"; However, I also added a simple get function to return the user name and I only get back "DEVW10$", which is the machine name. I should add, this worked fine on windows 10, running core6. I forced a W11 upgrade and it stopped working since. I reinstalled the core bundle after upgrade


Th edatabase is hosted locally,  do you mean the database is host also at the same server?

